# If a project's Ruby version is explicitly specified, could changing from RVM to rbenv introduce bugs?

Tags: bash, heroku, rvm, zsh, rbenv

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible that a bug I'm experiencing could be related to the fact that I use `rbenv` but the rest of my team uses `RVM`.

What I've been trying to figure out is whether the executables created by `rbenv`/`RVM` for a specific Ruby are the same. If the Ruby version and gem versions are explicitly specified in the `.ruby_version` and `Gemfile` respectively, is it possible that `rbenv` and `RVM` interpret code differently or should I expect identical outcomes?

**UPDATE. A description of the actual bug I'm experiencing was requested, so here it is.**

Essentially, the project is using the `dotenv` gem (and `dotenv-rails`) to read a `.env` file in the root directory. Two of the values (a salt and an IV) are Base64 encoded strings that contain newline characters. At some point in the decoding process, an extra backslash is being added before each newline character, causing the decryption to fail. The problem is, the `dotenv` gem appears to be reading the file correctly (i.e. running `Dotenv.load` in Rails console shows the strings parsed correctly), so it's some other gem or extension deeper in the stack causing the problem. And we have yet to identify it.

Our quick fix was to `gsub` the doubly escaped newlines (similar to [this `foreman` bug fix](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/pull/250/files), but some members of the team don't want to merge it because they're convinced it's an environment problem caused by `rbenv`. I don't think this is the case, but am wondering if it's a possibility before I try uninstalling `rbenv` and switching to `RVM`, which I *really* don't want to do.

**UPDATE #2. Problem solved!**

I did end up switching to `RVM`, but to no avail. However it did end up being an environment issue.

It was because my default shell is `zsh` but most of my team uses `bash`, and we were using `heroku local:run` to spin up the local dev environment. `heroku local:run`, it turns out, uses your default shell environment. Even if you make the call from a different shell (such as `bash`). However both `rails console` and `heroku local:run rails console` use `sh` by default. And `zsh` was handling the import of the env vars differently than `bash` and `sh`.

Comment: probably be the same ... why don't you say what the error you're getting is?

Comment: It's a little complex, and what I really want is someone to explain in depth if either RVM and rbenv have different build processes that result in different executables, or under the hood they're actually doing the same thing when building the Ruby executables. But I emailed a friend this same question, and he also wanted to know what the bug is, so once I get it typed up, I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the binaries compiled by rvm and rbenv are **not** the same, and they are **not** drop-in compatible. (e.g., you cannot compile `ruby` with rvm and then drop it into an existing rbenv setup) The compilation options provided to each are different, and the resulting files are handled differently.

That said, you should consider two `ruby` binaries of the same version that were compiled with the same options to be binary-compatible; that is, any Ruby code that runs through one binary should run the same way through the other binary, regardless of what platform they were compiled on, provided they were compiled with *the same options and libraries*.

For example, if rvm is compiled [without OpenSSL support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511943/troubles-with-rvm-and-openssl) you will have no end of trouble when trying to use libraries that rely on cryptographic functions. Likewise with bad versions of [readline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965491/how-to-reinstall-ruby-with-readline-support).

You can conduct a very simple experiment to determine the problem: compile `ruby` with both on the same computer and run your experiment through both versions.

For the specific problem you have outlined (dotenv and extra linebreaks), pay attention to [the difference between single quoted and double quoted strings](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Single_quotes), and how Ruby handles control characters in them. Ruby interprets escape sequences in double quoted strings only, so you can likely resolve your issue by ensuring your value is always single quoted.