# How to enable tab completion in old Ruby version using RVM?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I've installed old Ruby version (specifically, 2.2.3) using RVM and I need to have tab completion on it. I successfully installed tab completion on the current Ruby version, using `require "irb/completion"` in .irbrc file, and it works.

However, when I switch to 2.2.3 using RVM, I don't have tab completion. Attempt to locate .irbrc file in 2.2.3-version doesn't work, nothing changes. So how to enable it when I switch to old version?

Comment: You need the readline dev libraries preinstalled before you build Ruby. These might help: a) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965491/how-to-reinstall-ruby-with-readline-support b) https://superuser.com/a/299747/89010

Comment: Also have you made sure `irbrc` is actually loaded at all? Place a `puts "hello"` in it and run `irb` to check.

Comment: Irbrc is loaded, but the problem is that require "irb/completion" doesn't work somewhy.